# Get the ID of all child nodes from multiple treeview (skip parent node id). How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have used a treeview in a user control which is used multiple times in a single page showing different data. There would be only three levels of nodes (Parent - Child - Sub Child)

By default the parent node will be selected. when user click button, is it possible to get all the id of nodes (only child nodes and sub child nodes) which are selected in checkbox and validate for at least one child node to be selected from any treeview on the page ?

Note: Have to skip the ID of Parent node of all the tree.
      Have to get ID of all the child nodes and sub child nodes from all treeviews in the page.
      All the ID to be concatenated and separated by comma and store in a variable

Is this possible using Jquery or js ?

Rendered HTML :

```
<div id="ctl00_cphMain_pnl_left">

                <a href="#ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_SkipLink"><img alt="Skip Navigation Links." src="/WebResource.axd?d=vp_dPIRRqCpyFrxPBwqvPmsO-wa56CpxZGlT_T-AdX5QN0qJOs_wgfq4QMJwRILSj9XSONYmkJAe85CVEph0Q1SfUqs1&amp;t=634604712479085897" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;"></a><div id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index" onclick="OnTreeClick(event)" style="width:10px;font-size: 11px; font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','t1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c')"><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=_533LbcrYzxclETTqT9E9lbjpoP9iiSVLn9WP908dD96sH9D2JXH4BN8Q2OdATM4TYJU67kfDSnJQpffp_ITMVu3Y839pir-IzEhB41mqu6U8EWb0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt="Collapse Clinics" style="border-width:0;"></a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','s1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indext0">Clinics</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','s1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c\\8086a7e5-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indext1">Respite Care Services</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn2CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn2CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','s1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c\\5586a7e5-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indext2">Caregiver Training</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn3CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn3CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','s1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c\\643eafdf-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indext3">Psychiatric Rehabilitation Homes</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn4CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn4CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','s1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c\\613dafdf-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indext4">Befriending Service</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn5CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn5CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','s1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c\\6fe899f7-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indext5">Polyclinics</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn6CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn6CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','s1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c\\7393b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indext6">Caregiver Support Service</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=BOvsSO2B3BKMupOSRxbma89ER-i_r1FrqfnVsgVq_QiVog3IJUebdD29i4BVAo26-lbJh_BLXmsQGU_VArXhNt6ejiWJk87whzKer6ts-_kM9Vt90&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn7CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indexn7CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl03$Tree_Index','s1730b784-94ca-42d3-80aa-1c9c064e271c\\7a93b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Indext7">Helpline - Caregiver Helpline</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl03_Tree_Index_SkipLink"></a>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div[id $= Tree_Index]").find("input[type=checkbox]:first").click(function () {
            $(this).closest("div").find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
        });
    });
</script><a href="#ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_SkipLink"><img alt="Skip Navigation Links." src="/WebResource.axd?d=vp_dPIRRqCpyFrxPBwqvPmsO-wa56CpxZGlT_T-AdX5QN0qJOs_wgfq4QMJwRILSj9XSONYmkJAe85CVEph0Q1SfUqs1&amp;t=634604712479085897" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;"></a><div id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index" onclick="OnTreeClick(event)" style="width:10px;font-size: 11px; font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','tace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7')"><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=_533LbcrYzxclETTqT9E9lbjpoP9iiSVLn9WP908dD96sH9D2JXH4BN8Q2OdATM4TYJU67kfDSnJQpffp_ITMVu3Y839pir-IzEhB41mqu6U8EWb0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt="Collapse Home Care" style="border-width:0;"></a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext0">Home Care</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','tace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\0f93b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')"><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=PtoZaOE4OJ68kA17eB1Ru-nLDbZ-ilvB8z5abVJ8BfKZp0iKKZ8iPpsV8tJ5bLWmNAAyfP3gCpxQRyrUtuHqeJKGILYd8Nbb3deoYK17HD9ZYyeS0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt="Collapse Home Nursing" style="border-width:0;"></a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\0f93b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext1">Home Nursing</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=J9BSVEmYJ2R79DzKPp_KwudhxkmRYjt31taLGpqjHFuG3gyciimdNIz2hfef3rMTcgKKF9rZcFetwoS-fvXnw3uYWh88CZ98-dNXPYEoMwTaffwZ0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn2CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn2CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\0f93b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039\\00000000-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext2">Third Level 1</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=J9BSVEmYJ2R79DzKPp_KwudhxkmRYjt31taLGpqjHFuG3gyciimdNIz2hfef3rMTcgKKF9rZcFetwoS-fvXnw3uYWh88CZ98-dNXPYEoMwTaffwZ0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=BOvsSO2B3BKMupOSRxbma89ER-i_r1FrqfnVsgVq_QiVog3IJUebdD29i4BVAo26-lbJh_BLXmsQGU_VArXhNt6ejiWJk87whzKer6ts-_kM9Vt90&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn3CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn3CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\0f93b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039\\11111111-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext3">Third Level 2</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn4CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn4CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\c13eafdf-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext4">Private Nursing Homes</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn5CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn5CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\1493a4eb-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext5">Personal Healthcare Assistant</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn6CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn6CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\f592b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext6">Home Medical</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn7CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn7CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\2493b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext7">Home Therapy - Physiotherapy</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn8CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn8CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\1a93b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext8">Home Therapy - Occupational Therapy</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn9CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn9CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\083eafdf-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext9">Social Day Care Services</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn10CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn10CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\e7ba9bfd-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext10">Community VWO Clinics</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn11CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn11CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\b292b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext11">Day Rehabilitation Services</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn12CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn12CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\2087a7e5-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext12">Community Wellness Clubs</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=BOvsSO2B3BKMupOSRxbma89ER-i_r1FrqfnVsgVq_QiVog3IJUebdD29i4BVAo26-lbJh_BLXmsQGU_VArXhNt6ejiWJk87whzKer6ts-_kM9Vt90&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn13CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indexn13CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl04$Tree_Index','sace7ae2e-c160-4982-a90f-785fc5b7cca7\\8f93b4d9-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Indext13">Community Hospitals</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl04_Tree_Index_SkipLink"></a>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div[id $= Tree_Index]").find("input[type=checkbox]:first").click(function () {
            $(this).closest("div").find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
        });
    });
</script><a href="#ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index_SkipLink"><img alt="Skip Navigation Links." src="/WebResource.axd?d=vp_dPIRRqCpyFrxPBwqvPmsO-wa56CpxZGlT_T-AdX5QN0qJOs_wgfq4QMJwRILSj9XSONYmkJAe85CVEph0Q1SfUqs1&amp;t=634604712479085897" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;"></a><div id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index" onclick="OnTreeClick(event)" style="width:10px;font-size: 11px; font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl05$Tree_Index','tfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f')"><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=_533LbcrYzxclETTqT9E9lbjpoP9iiSVLn9WP908dD96sH9D2JXH4BN8Q2OdATM4TYJU67kfDSnJQpffp_ITMVu3Y839pir-IzEhB41mqu6U8EWb0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt="Collapse Other Services" style="border-width:0;"></a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn0CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indext0">Other Services</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn1CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f\\45bb0a98-ec44-e211-beaf-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indext1">Mobile Services</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn2CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn2CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f\\9b3dafdf-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indext2">Hospice Day Care</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn3CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn3CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f\\f83dafdf-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indext3">Website - Disability Information Website</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=Ptpr_s5NKQd2NhXQH_MiSClxDVR5ZHar9QZwFenhB3L_8-vIXRA_NHlxqP3iWPQWzSbDizVZ5YO8o3q4fX1XUhismQEMBdpf8AuHvaSyrvYco4WB0&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn4CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn4CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f\\33333333-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indext4">Information &amp; Referral Services</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-width:0;">
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><div style="width:20px;height:1px"></div></td><td><img src="/WebResource.axd?d=BOvsSO2B3BKMupOSRxbma89ER-i_r1FrqfnVsgVq_QiVog3IJUebdD29i4BVAo26-lbJh_BLXmsQGU_VArXhNt6ejiWJk87whzKer6ts-_kM9Vt90&amp;t=634604712479085897" alt=""></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="checkbox" name="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn5CheckBox" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indexn5CheckBox"><a class="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$cphMain$ctl05$Tree_Index','sfc052442-3b20-4cdc-8d20-9c8544ac1c6f\\44444444-217e-e111-9ca9-005056ba0039')" id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Indext5">Ambulance Service (Non-Emergency)</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div><a id="ctl00_cphMain_ctl05_Tree_Index_SkipLink"></a>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div[id $= Tree_Index]").find("input[type=checkbox]:first").click(function () {
            $(this).closest("div").find(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
        });
    });
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will recurse through a node and its family, grabing all id's that it comes across

```
function onEvent(ParentNode)
{
    var ids = [];
    GetIds(ParentNode.childNodes,ids);
    console.log(ids.join(","));
}

function GetIds(Family,ids)
{
    for(var i=0,j=Family.length; i<j; i++)
    {
        if(Family[i].id)ids[ids.length] = Family[i].id;
        if(Family[i].childNodes)GetIds(Family[i].childNodes,ids);
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I used this code to fit my needs. Can you please elaborate on this ? thanks.

Comment: `<div id="ctl00_cphMain_pnl_left" onclick='onEvent(this)'>{Content containing child nodes}</div>` will log all ID's held within the div when it is clicked. Instead of `console.log` you can set any variable to `ids.join(',')`. I think you can work out the rest